# Could not get the image file path from the storage folder. What am i missing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Here is the code that saves my image inside /storage/app/public folder

```
$path = $request->file('question_image')->store('public');
```

The laravel 5.3 documentation says I have to create a symbolic link from /public/storage to /storage/app/public folder hence I did by using command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

At this point I am successful to store my images inside /storage/app/public.

Now what is understood is that I can get those files using

```
echo asset('storage/file_name.jpeg');
```

But no luck whatsoever.

Please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Try `storage_path() . "/app/public/" . $file_name`

Comment: Do you want a link to display your images on a website or a direct path to the image?

Comment: I want a link not direct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this if what you need is the URL of the file: `url(Storage::url('public/photo.jpg));`

Otherwise just use `Storage::url('public/photo.jpg);` to get just the path.

Comment: Thanks Storage::url('public/photo.jpg'); solves the problem.. Thank you very much. Anyways couldn't find the function ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image from storage you can use this in your blade file:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/image.jpg')}}">
```